# How Handle a button click on python/Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm building an small application and want to handle a button click using Flask. What do i need to add to get it working>

If you have the following in the template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Button Pressed: {{ButtonPressed}} </h2>
       <input type="submit" value="Click Me" >
     </div>

</body>
```

And the following in `.py`

```
Button Pressed = 0        
@app.route('/button', methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def button():
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render_template("button.html", ButtonPressed = ButtonPressed)
        return redirect(url_for('button'))
```

I search a lot, but all of it is in like a form. But this should not be in a form right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a form in your HTML.

Comment: You are not sending any request to the server on button click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be within a form for it to be submitted.

Method-1:

```
`<div class="container">
    <h2>Button Pressed: {{ButtonPressed}}</h2>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Click Me" >
    </form>
 </div>`
```

Python -

```
ButtonPressed = 0        
@app.route('/button', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def button():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return render_template("button.html", ButtonPressed = ButtonPressed)
        # I think you want to increment, that case ButtonPressed will be plus 1.
    return render_template("button.html", ButtonPressed = ButtonPressed)
```

Method 2 -

Use Ajax to submit form. Read the documentation here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Submit a post request and your Flask application will send ButtonPressed incremented value to the function, and you can process value however you want. Still, you need a form for this and you need to update ButtonPressed value using JavaScript. However, ButtonPressed value should be maintained in some database if you need it to be stored.

Method 3 -

Without a form, you can make  link look like button using Bootstrap and update it directly on UI in case you don't need the ButtonPressed value stored somewhere which will also avoid unnecessary call to server (you don't want to store it). Bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 4):

It must be in a form, or you must use Javascript.

There are two ways you can use to handle a button click. One way is to use a form, and the other is to use jQuery (though vanilla JS would suffice).

If you decide to use forms, obviously, your button should be inside a form. The end result would look something like the one below.

```
<div class="container">
    ...
    <form action="/button" method="get"> <!-- or method="post" -->
        <input type="submit" value="Click Me" >
    </form>
    ...
</div>
```

If you decide to use jQuery, you must handle button presses. You would then need to send a `GET` request to `/button` if the button is pressed. Your button should be given an `id` so that we could easily identify which button we are handling.

Your jQuery code would then look something similar to the one below.

```
$("input").click(function() { // or $("input#<input id, if it has one>")...
    $.get('/button');
    // If you want to post to the backend instead, do
    // $.post('/button');
});
```

Your `.py` file would usually just remain the same for both cases.

#### Side note

You might want to increment `ButtonPressed` in your `.py` file in a request every time a request is sent `/button` (i.e. whenever the button is pressed). Your Python file would look something like this:

```
ButtonPressed = 0        
@app.route('/button', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def button():
    if request.method == "POST":
        ButtonPressed += 1  # Note this increment here.
        return render_template("button.html", ButtonPressed = ButtonPressed)
    return redirect(url_for('button'))
```

If you don't increment `ButtonPressed`, `0` will always be displayed instead of the number of times the button was pressed.

---

## Addendum

If you are sending `POST` requests from the form (i.e. using `method="post"` instead of `method="get"`) or the jQuery code (i.e. using `$.post(...)` instead of `$.get(...)`), your code should be modified to accept `POST` requests instead of `GET` requests. In other words, your `.py` file should contain something like the one below.

```
ButtonPressed = 0        
@app.route('/button', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def button():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return render_template("button.html", ButtonPressed = ButtonPressed)
    return redirect(url_for('button'))
```

If you are thinking of accepting both `GET` and `POST` requests for `/button`, just add an `or` condition to the conditional statement. Your conditional statement will be `if request.method == "POST" or request.method == "GET"`.