# don't get value on button press in html

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask

I have a button which when clicked just need to execute a javascript function. The javascript function returns a string which I intend to capture in the flask backend. Currently the javascript function runs on onclick.

The code:

```
<form id='details'method="post">
     <input class="myButton" id="mybutton" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="getdata()">
     </input>
</form>
```

The flask code:

```
app.add_url_rule('/entry1', endpoint='entry1', view_func=new_data, methods=['GET', 'POST'] )

def new_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        details = request.form['details']
        print(details)
```

In flask, when I am giving request.forms['details'], i don't get anything. I expect to get returned data from getdata. I am pretty sure, theres some issue in html side. Please advice.

Got a lot of comments regarding the same, but it doesn't fix...just wonder if there is any other way to handling it, I just need text collected on button click to be transferred to python backend, it seems pretty simple, but just cant get this done :(
Thanks

Comment: If my answer did not help, then share also the python code

Comment: what does `getdata()` do ?

Comment: getdata captures all data from text boxes and combines to a string. it then returns the string

Comment: where it return values  in some textbox ? make sure that textbox is inside your form.

Answer (score 0):

---

> > > > > **#EDIT 2** check this answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request).

I report here the most of it as referance:

- [`request.args`][2]: the key/value pairs in the URL query string
- [`request.form`][3]: the key/value pairs in the body, from a HTML post form, or JavaScript request that isn't JSON encoded
- [`request.files`][4]: the files in the body, which Flask keeps separate from `form`. HTML forms must use `enctype=multipart/form-data` or files will not be uploaded.
- [`request.values`][5]: combined `args` and `form`, preferring `args` if keys overlap
- [`request.json`][6]: parsed JSON data. The request must have the `application/json` content type, or use [`request.get_json(force=True)`][7] to ignore the content type.

All of these are [`MultiDict`][8] instances (except for `json`). You can access values using:

- `request.form['name']`: use indexing if you know the key exists
- `request.form.get('name')`: use `get` if the key might not exist
- `request.form.getlist('name')`: use `getlist` if the key is sent multiple times and you want a list of values. `get` only returns the first value.

---

First it would be helpful if you also add the flask code. That's being said, add this to the input tag:

```
<form id='details'method="post">
     <input class="myButton" name="details" id="mybutton" type="submit" value="Save" 
     onclick="getdata()">
 </input>
</form>
```

So basically you had a 'name=""' field to it.

Then in the python file, use this:

```
request.form['details']
```

Even better if you store the value in a variable (obviously that's depend you, is just a suggestion)

```
request_detail = request.form['details']
```

Also in the form tag you may want to add a 'action=""' field. This depends on how route Decorator in the flask.

Example if you have this:

```
@app.route('/details)
def details():
    pass
```

Then your form should have this:

```
<form id='details'method="post" action="/details">
```

or

```
<form id='details'method="post" action="details">
```

---

> > > EDIT

Try to use a normal route decorator to see if it fixes:

```
@app.route('/entry1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        details = request.form['details']
        print(details)
    return render_template('filename.html')
```

If you still want to use the add_url_rule try this:

```
app.add_url_rule('/', 'entry1', view_func=new_data, methods=['GET', 'POST'] )
```

---

Comment: oops, if I do request.form['details'], then I get 'Save' as in button.value.

Comment: I dont' understand what you mean? can you specify better?

Comment: Did you try to add 'name=""' tag?

Comment: yes, i added, but when i access it from python code, i just get value of the button which is "Save", not the returned value of getdata

Comment: is there a  return render_template in the new_data(): function?

Comment: Also the issue may be because of a JavaScript Funciont (which I currently not really familiar with) so If my solution did not help, check also this answers:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482475/how-handle-a-button-click-on-python-flask             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601478/flask-calling-python-function-on-button-onclick-event

Comment: how adding name will fix it mate? cause it returns the value of the button ehich is "Save"

Comment: Because = request.forms['details'], 'details' is equal to what name="details" is. However as I say it may be due to javascritpt. @reminder faisal may have found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting nothing in flask **request.form['details']**, because the data was sent using javascript. You should try:

```
request.data  # if data was sent as plain text
```

or

```
request.get_json() # if data was sent as json
```

Comment: Oops, nope, I dont get anything if i say details=request.data, i just get b'' as details value...am badly stuck in seemingly an innoocous problem :(